# Django site cant be reached

Tags: python, django

I run the server in c9 (django workspace). There were no errors and it said

> Starting development server at `http://127.0.0.1:8000//`.

However, when i open this site it says

> This site can’t be reached
>    127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Can anyone help me fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation says that you use a URL they give to you (not localhost) to access the server

> Use the Share button on the top to figure out the URLs of running Application and the Preview.

See https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application#section--pre-view-your-application

Answer (score 5):

127.0.0.1 is your local computer, not the c9 instance. The docs refer to a unique URL for each app, like: `http://<workspacename>-<username>.c9users.io:8081`

So, try using runserver like this: `python manage.py runserver $IP:$PORT`

You can then look in your browser tab for the server address that you can see your app running on, which will be similar to the one above. You'll use that when testing instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Check out the Django guide on their [site](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-django/1727)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy server, you can check the "do not use proxy for local addresses" button in the proxy settings. for me this worked.