# While accessing 127.0.0.1:8000,it is not working, i am getting message like this site can't be reached

Tags: python, http, server, command

I entered **python -m http.server** to start server and i got message like server started on port 8000 but while accessing through the browser i am getting message like this site can't be reached.

Comment: Print the port and host in console. You will get the address properly

Comment: There is a previous answer here that should cover this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207540/django-site-cant-be-reached

Comment: Oh sorry,by mistakely i added django tag.

Comment: Yes i saw that but it is related to django. but i am working on frontend part like html,css & javascript.